# To test working of xml in iphone?

Tags: iphone, xml

HI can i place both xml files and images that the xml file transports in xcode to test the working since i don't have the internet ? If it can be done , what should be the path name for the xml to be coded in program and images to be typed in xml.?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *stringToXML = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"theXMLDoc" ofType:@"xml"];
NSURL *XMLURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringToXML];
```

Using that you can get XML documents from the resource folder and use them.

Just substitute your url in your code for the variable `XMLURL` and you should be fine. Its the same for images, you just need to make an NSURL out of the path resource.

Comment: NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"imagesexample" ofType: @"xml"];
 NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: path];
 NSLog (@"XML path is  %@", path);
 NSXMLParser* parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: data];
 
 [parser setDelegate:self];
 [parser parse];
 [parser release];

Comment: I given url  for path then, When i display using NSlog(), it geting null value

Comment: After parse how to access the contents ?

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about. If you're having issue with a specific bit of code please post a new question, post up the code you have and explain what is not working. :)